# Border between cells in a WPF UniformGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new to WPF, and trying to add a 1 pixel border or space between elements in a UniformGrid. How can I do this? I tried adding a Margin to each child element, but that creates a two pixel border between cells in the middle. I could add a margin to top and left, but that would make the bottom and right cells have no outside margin.

I tried googling, probably not using the right terms.

Comment: Hi, just by the by - are you sure you're using the right type of panel as UniformGrid is a resizable control? Can you not set your left margin to the width of your border and the very last one will have the right margin too? As far as I know no standard controls in wpf would support the functionality you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said you tried setting Margin to 1, which gives you a total of 2 pixels around each element.

So cut it in half; set your items' margins to 0.5 instead. You'll also want to add a Margin of 0.5 to the UniformGrid itself, so everything ends up lining up on pixel boundaries.

(The leftmost column of items will have the UniformGrid's 0.5-pixel left margin, plus the item's 0.5-pixel margin, for a total of 1 pixel. Then between that first column and the next column, you'll have the first column's 0.5-pixel right margin, plus the next column's 0.5-pixel left margin, so once again you've got 1 pixel total between columns. It works out nicely.)

Answer (score 2):

Option 1: `Grid` panel with `ShowGridLines` property, but there're just dashed lines.

Option 2: `DataGrid` with `GridLinesVisibility=DataGridGridLinesVisibility.All`. Here you could specify different line brushes with `VerticalGridLinesBrush` and `HorizontalGridLinesBrush`

Option 3: Own panel

I believe that there're more options, but I know just those I listed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the markup only solution, you can create a DP - Border width and bind to it, just give us a shout if you a need help on:

```
<Window x:Class="Margins.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:s="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Border Background="Green" Padding="0,0,10,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Rectangle Fill="White" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10,10,0,10"/>
                <Rectangle Fill="White" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10,10,0,10" />
                <Rectangle Fill="White" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10,10,0,10" />
                <Rectangle Fill="White" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="10,10,0,10" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```